# Why can't contour text along curve path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations, contour

I want to use a font with a white contour but doesn't seems to work.

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \font\f=cmr17 at20pt;
    \node (inicio) at (-3.9cm, -0.95cm) {};
    \node (fin) at (4.1cm,-0.75cm) {};   
    \draw[decoration={text along path,
           text={|\f|\contour{red}|This is a long sample text|||},
           text align={center}},decorate]  (inicio) to [out=-2,in=520]  (fin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7):

You may use the `text effects along path` decoration to apply the `\contour` command to each character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mycontour#1{\contour{red}#1}
  \node (inicio) at (-3.9cm, -0.95cm) {};
  \node (fin) at (4.1cm,-0.75cm) {};   
  \draw[
    decoration={text effects along path,
      text={This is a long sample text},
      text align=center,
      text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      every character/.style={font=\huge,character command=\mycontour}
    },decorate
  ]  (inicio) to [out=-2,in=160]  (fin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** here is a better version.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mycontour#1{\textcolor{white}{\contour{red}{#1}}}
  \node (inicio) at (-3.9cm, -0.95cm) {};
  \node (fin) at (4.1cm,-0.75cm) {};   
  \draw[
  decoration={text effects along path,
    text={This is a long sample text},
    text align=center,
    text effects/.cd,
    text along path, scale text to path,
    characters={font=\Huge,character command=\mycontour},
  },decorate,
  ]  (inicio) to [out=-2,in=160]  (fin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. One might wish to use `postaction=decorate` (or `preaction`) so the curve also appears.